# Scrapy does not process TBODY in Xpath and CSS selector

Tags: python, css, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to parse this HTML.

```
<table id="ctl00_LeftColumnMiddle_Table1" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td >Contractor Name</td><td>UNITED RENTALS HIGHWAY TECHNOLOGIES INC</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><table border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td >Contractor Name</td><td>UNITED RENTALS NORTHWEST INC</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It has several TRs in `#ctl00_LeftColumnMiddle_Table1` and has a `table` inside each `tr`

I want to process each record (a TR in fact) and then process details of each record.

I have tried these selectors/Xpaths.

```
Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_LeftColumnMiddle_Table1"]/tbody/tr')
```

and

```
Selector(response).css('#ctl00_LeftColumnMiddle_Table1 > tbody >tr')
```

But this returns no results.

But if I do

```
Selector(response).css('#ctl00_LeftColumnMiddle_Table1 tr')
```

But this expression also selects inner `tr`s with `Contractor Name` too.

Is this a bug in Scrapy?

If it is, is there any other way to process records the way I want?

Comment: `tbody` is a tag which is generated automatically, so you'd better avoid using it in selectors

Answer (score 8):

I did it with

```
Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_LeftColumnMiddle_Table1"]/tr')
```

or

```
Selector(response).css('#ctl00_LeftColumnMiddle_Table1 > tr')
```

It is because `tbody` is tag automatically added by browsers like Firefox and Chrome.

But when scraping with Scrapy, `tbody` was not there in the `response` HTML.

Comment: The important part is that "tbody" may not exist in the raw html structure that you traverse over using xpath. It's automatically added by browsers to the DOM.

Answer (score -2):

```
In [2]: from scrapy.selector import Selector

In [3]: sel = Selector(text=text)

In [4]: sel.xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_LeftColumnMiddle_Table1"]/tbody/tr')
Out[4]: 
[<Selector xpath='//*[@id="ctl00_LeftColumnMiddle_Table1"]/tbody/tr' data='<tr>\n            <td>\n                <t'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@id="ctl00_LeftColumnMiddle_Table1"]/tbody/tr' data='<tr>\n            <td><table border="0">\n'>]
```

you xpath works.

please use `view(response)` to open the response in the browser, make sure the tag exist in the response.